# Using Git, how can I log all commits that are merge commits between two specific branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log

Say my Git repository has the branches `master`, `BranchA`, `BranchB`, and `BranchC`.

Now all of these branches have been merged into master, possibly multiple times (for whatever reason, it's a hypothetical scenario).  I want to be able to find all of the merge commits where `BranchA` was merged into `master`.

Here is as far as I got before asking this question:

```
git log master ^BranchA --merges --oneline
```

This gets me all of the commits that are in `master` and not `BranchA` that are also merge commits.  This actually gives me all of the commits I am looking for, but it can also give me commits I do not want, such as merges from `BranchB` and `BranchC` into master.

Example output:

```
10bdc8b Merge branch 'BranchA'
383693a Merge branch 'BranchB'
8af3b5c Merge branch 'master' of 192.168.0.0:/path/to/repo.git
aa0f22c Merge branch 'master' into BranchC
72bbf3a Merge branch 'BranchA'
fac1157 Merge branch 'BranchB'
```

I would like to find a solution that outputs just the `10bdc8b` and `72bbf3a`. And don't just grep for the name 'BranchA'; I know that would work in this case, but it is always possible that the merge commit could be given a custom message, so it may not always work.

---

**Edit**

Good responses so far, but unfortunately, I have hit a wall that I don't know how to get past.  Consider the following scenario:

```
   F                               <-BranchB
  / \        
 /   \        
A-----B----C-----D--E----K----L    <-master
       \        /    \       /
        \      /      \     /
         G----H--------I---J       <-BranchA
```

Now, my goal here is to find all the merge commits from BranchA to master.  By looking at the graph, I can see that I am looking for `L` and `D`.  The curve ball that is keeping me from figuring this out programmatically however, is the merge commit `I` where master is merged into BranchA.

In this scenario, if we use the `branch --contains` method on all commits in master, we get `L`,`D`,and `B`. However, if we do branch --contains on all commits in master and not in BranchA, we get only `L`.  Neither approach gets the desired output.

Similarly, if we use `git merge-base` to find the parent, we get only `L`.

As far as I can tell, there does not seem to be a good way to separate `B` and `D`, since both commits are in the history of BranchA.  I can tell by looking at them that they are different, but Git does not seem to have a good way to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command in git to obtain all the merges from a specific branch, but you can combine `branch --contains` and merge parents walk to get close. Ignoring octopus commits, on the master branch we are interested in the second merge parent:

```
bash$ for commit in \
        $(git log --format=%h --merges --max-parents=2 master ^topic); do \
          [[ $(git branch --contains ${commit}^2) =~ topic ]] && \
          echo $commit; done
```

Of course you will have to make sure that no merges fast-forward, that is, you will have to specify the `--no-ff` switch when you merge, otherwise you'll lose the necessary two-parent branching that the scriplet above relies on.

There is an additional consideration, and whether it is a complication depends on your specific use cases. In the following example,

```
I--A--M---N---O---F  ← master
 \   /       /   /
  `-B-------D ← / ← topicA
     \         /
      `--C----E ← topicB
```

The commit `B` is a parent of a merge commit `M` and an ancestor of both `E` and `D`. When you query about merge commits on `master`, you will get commits `F,O,M` and then when you query which of those was a `topicA` branch merge, you will get `M,O` but you will also get `M` when you ask which of those was a `topicB` branch merge, this is really since `B` is an ancestor of both branches.

Comment: Good. One small correction needed to your bash script. "git log --format=%h --merges master" needs to be "git log --format=%h --merges master ^<desired branch>"  Otherwise you will get all of the merge commits from before the desired branch was created.  Also, we could specify --max-parents=2 to avoid octopus commits... still not sure how I want to handle those.

Comment: @jacobhyphenated Excellent points - updated the answer with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to get this in Git, but I have an idea how I would go about solving it.  If it were me, I'd be doing this in Python.  Other people would probably do it in Bash.

First, I'd get a list of merge commits in A along with the parents they are merging:

```
git log --merges --format="%H %P" A
```

I would iterate over each line in the result looking at the third hash (assuming all merges are of two parents only).  The first hash on the line is the hash of the merge commit itself -- that's what we want as the answer if this merge turns out to be between A and B.  The second hash is the parent in the A branch.  The third hash is the other parent, which we want to test for membership in B.  So, for each (third) hash, I would call

```
git merge-base B <hash>
```

...and if the result was the same as the hash I put in, that commit (the first hash on the line) is a merge into branch A of branch B.

Comment: I sometimes have trouble keeping git merge-base straight, but in this case, would not "git mergebase B <first commit>" is equal to <third commit> be what we are trying to do?